# What is the deference between identically non-vanishing function and non vanishing function

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Some where I read the two following notions:
"Identically non-vanishing function of complex variable" &
"non vanishing function of complex variable".
Are they the same?
What I know is tha a non-vanishing function is such that $f(x)\neq 0~~ \forall x\in R$. Is it the same in complex set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two notions are the same. The use of the word identically is usually meant to emphasize uniformity across the domain, or something like that.

E.g. $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=0$ is identically $0$ on its domain.